# no matching function for call to 'Book::Book()'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am doing something for a MIT OCW course and it asks to write a 'library' class . Right now I have this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Book{
    string title;
    bool rented;
public:
    Book(string bookTitle){
        title = bookTitle;
    }
    void borrowed(){
        rented = true;
    }
    void returned(){
        rented = false;
    }
    bool isBorrowed(){
        return rented;
    }
    string getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
};

class Library{
    string Lname;
    Book bookList[100000000];
    int numOfBooks = 0;
public:
    Library(string name){
        Lname = name;
    }
    void addBook(string bookName){
        bookList[numOfBooks] = Book(bookName);
        numOfBooks += 1;
    }
    void returnInfo(){
    cout << "Library hours:" << "\n" << "Libraries are open daily from 9am to 5pm." << "\n" << "Library addresses:" << "\n" << "10 Main St." << "\n" << "228 Liberty St.";
    }

};
int main()
{
    Library l = Library("Hi");
    return 0;
}
```

And when I compile it gives me the error no matching function for call to 'Book::Book()' for line 35.

Comment: No need to create and copy something just to have an object. Do `Library l("Hi");`.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler complains that you haven't defined default constructor for Book, you could try this:

```
 explicit Book(const string& bookTitle = std::string("")) 
 : title(bookTitle) 
 {
 }
```

Define 100000000 on stack my cause overflow,

```
Book bookList[100000000];
```

try to use vector instead

```
std::vector<Book> bookList;
```

In addBook, you could simply use [std::vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) to add a new book. To get total book number, use [std::vector::size()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size)

```
void addBook(const string& bookName){
    bookList.push_back(Book(bookName));
}
```

Suggestion:

> 1. To pass parameter to function like std::string, pass by const
> 2. reference is a better way. use member initialization list if possible

```
 Library(const string& name) : Lname(name) {  }
 void addBook(const string& bookName){ }
```

Comment: It seems he is being over-precautions with the `100000000` figure. He doesn't necessarily need that many books, and he is keeping track of how many he is actually using with a separate integer.  So if he is going to make the switch to vector (as he most definitely should), then there is probably no need to initialize the vector with that many books.  Drop the `numOfBooks` variable, use `push_back` in the `addBook` function, and let the vector do its own bookkeeping.

Comment: Oh, and I just realized something else.  As an added bonus, if he uses this method, he no longer needs the default constructor, which was really just a crutch to satisfy his flawed initial implementation.

Comment: when i use the vector instead, it says that:                      error: 'vector' in namespace 'std' does not name a type

Answer (score 0):

```
Book bookList[100000000];
```

Will try to create 100000000 object with default constructor..

Answer (score 0):

the  **bookList** is created as an array of objects not as an array of string and then you are assigning **strings(bookName)** to **bookList** so i think the problem lies here.